# kendo treeview finished rendering event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview, kendo-ui

Is there any method of knowing when a Kendo TreeView component has finished rendering? I'm loading a large data set at once and the browser is useless during the rendering stage (ASP.Net MVC 4). I would like to use such a "RenderingFinished" event to signal the user that they can start browsing the data. I currently open a busy icon on the data source "RequestStart" event and close it on the "DataBound" event of the TreeView. The problem is that this only catches the data retrieval and not the actual "visual" tree construction. The user starts clicking on the webpage not knowing that the browser has not finished rendering the tree. This leads to the browser freezing and the user getting frustrated. How can I keep the busy icon on until the tree has finished rendering?

Comment: If the tree is so large that it takes long time to get rendered, did you consider getting one level at a time, i.e. using [loadOnDemand](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#configuration-loadOnDemand)

Comment: I did try using `loadOnDemand` but without any success, as when I load the entire tree I need all the nodes to be expanded. This runs as expected when I load each node at a time. In my current scenario I have, for example, a node with ~700 children, not mentioning descendants. Event if there where no other descendants than it's direct children, the node would still take long to render. Lazy loading and virtualization is what I need but I can't figure out how to achieve this so I decided to try to just tell the user that the browser is busy...

Comment: Um! Load On Demand does not help if you need to load everything. The problem is the size of the tree, is it usable? I cannot imagine managing myself having 700 nodes and have to search through them. I would have preferred some cascade autocomplete, or something like that.

Comment: The tree follows a specific hierarchy (described in an XML file). Based on this structure it queries the data from the database and renders it in the browser. There are situations when the user wants all the data at once. These are the requirements... The structure is already cascaded (to some extent). The data corresponding to the specific structure can be huge. We all (project related people) know that. And take it as such. We just need some signaling. We want to say "hey, the browser is busy, go have a coffee or a bagel while the data loads; when there's no busy icon, you can come back".